# Site Navigation Controller in Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, navigation, fat-free-framework

I am trying to create a separate Controller to handle site navigation, which is pretty much constant throughout the site, like Main Navigation and Sidebar Navigation and possible Footer Navigation.

I cannot figure how I should do it without specifically creating a route for this, my assumption is that: if the navigation controller is something that should work on its own and anywhere across my site, which means that I cannot specify some sort of rout as it will not work on every page unless I call it in other methods.

### Routing

```
GET / = MainController->render
GET /@category_slug = CategoryController->CategorySlug
```

My current code is as follows:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function navigation(){
        $categories = new Categories($this->db);
        $cat = $categories->all();
        $this->f3->set('categories',$cat);
    }

    function CategorySlug(){
        $category_slug = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.category_slug');
        $categories = new Categories($this->db);
        $cat = $categories->getBySlug($category_slug);
        $header_location = $cat[0]['category_slug'];
        if($category_slug != $header_location && !empty($header_location)){
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: $header_location");
        }else if(empty($header_location) || $cat[0]['category_id'] != $cat[0]['parent_category_id']){
            $this->f3->error(404);
        }else{
            $this->f3->set('category',$cat[0]);
        }
        $this->f3->set('view','mainCategory.html');
        $this->navigation();
        echo \Template::instance()->render('mainLayout.html');
    }
}
```

So as youi can see from the code, the first method is my site navigation, which I need to call in the second method to display the navigation on the Category Page. Same goes for my Home page, here is my code for it:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{

    function render(){
        $classNav = new CategoryController();
        $classNav->navigation();
        $this->f3->set('view','mainHome.html');
        echo \Template::instance()->render('mainLayout.html');
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a `beforeroute` method into your controller, according to https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#EventHandlers.
This method is called before any other route handler in your class and can be used to prepare data that is needed across all other parts of your site.

Comment: This could work, I for some reason I thought that you can only use it for session and headers, perhaps I was wrong, thank you